# Create a column based on multiple column distinct count pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
Family  Product     Date    Price
A           1   7/17/2017    3
B           3   2/5/2018     5
A           1   7/17/2017    4
A           1   7/17/2017    4
B           3   2/5/2018     5
```

I want my output to look like

```
Family  Product     Date    Price Count
A           1   7/17/2017    3      2
B           3   2/5/2018     5      1
A           1   7/17/2017    4      2
A           1   7/17/2017    4      2
B           3   2/5/2018     5      1
```

The code I am trying to get the desired output(distinct count of price per three columns)

```
df['Count']=df.groupby(['Family','Product','Date'])['Price'].nunique()
```

and the error I am getting is "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index". I hope someone could help me with this

Comment: I see you unaccept my answer, it was accident? Or some problem?

Comment: @Nipun, read [What  you should do when someone-answers your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: It was by accident, I am really sorry for that. I just came to thank you :)